# Teradata connector stage issue: Setting null values for field with Timestamp datatype to Server time

Tags: timestamp, teradata, connector, datastage

I have a Teradata connector stage in my project. The table has few fields with Timesheet datatype. These fields have Null values. When I view the data from View data option available in the stage, it is showing up as empty. But when I am fetching the output of same to Sequential file, all the NULL values in timestamp fields are being converted to Server timestamp. But I need the NULL values unchanged in my output file. How should I fix this? Kindly help. Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Aakanksha.

Comment: Please show us your code for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of "NULL" in Sequential File, you have to define a value you want to represent "NULL" in it.

This is the step in Sequential File Stage to default a "NULL" value.
Format Tab -> Field Defaults -> Null Field Value.